# Show a TM-recognizable language of TMs can be expressed by TM-description language of equivalent TMs

Tags: turing-machines, computability, decision-problem

I am studying "An Introduction to the Theory of Computation" by Sipser -- there is a problem *3.17 (p.161) which I can not solve. 
Any *hints* (not *answers*) from which side to attack it?

> Let $B=\{M_1, M_2, ...\}$ be a Turing-recognizable language consisting of TM descriptions. Show that there is a *decidable* language C consisting of TM descriptions s.t. every machine in B has an equivalent machine in C and vice versa.

Comment: note: the answer by Shaull is wrong and should be deleted.

Comment: Indeed, I seemed to have missed the "and vice versa" in the question. Since the answer is accepted, I cannot delete it. If the user is still around, then please un-accept, so I can delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technical hint: assume that every string is a legal encoding of a TM. Can you solve this now?

Intuitive hint: the language $C$ can contain many other encodings as well as those that are equivalent to the machines in $B$. Perhaps so many that $C$ becomes decidable.

Comment: either your technical hint or the fact that "TM-rec language has an enumerator that prints all $M_i$ one by one" helped to solve it!) i put the answer (hope correct) [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/444947/posts/cs.stackexchange.com_questions_14680_homework-show-a-tm-recognizable-language-of-tms-can-be-expressed-by-tm-dec-lan.html)

Comment: Indeed. In a way, $\Sigma^*$ satisfies this.

Comment: @Shaull this would not work, as you need also that for any TM description in $C$ there would exist an equivalent TM description in $B$.

Comment: @user44551 - you're right, of course. I don't know what I was thinking back then.

Comment: @Ayrat  file not found.

Comment: @Idonotknow dropbox changed it:( https://www.dropbox.com/s/saobnwlp0tds4fw/cs.stackexchange.com_questions_14680_homework-show-a-tm-recognizable-language-of-tms-can-be-expressed-by-tm-dec-lan.html?dl=0

Comment: Could not understand what is written @Ayrat

Comment: This answer is wrong and should be deleted. @Idonotknow [here's a pastebin of Ayrat's solution](https://pastebin.com/5EFkGSqk). However, both that solution as well as the hints given in this answer are wrong, for the reason described by user44551.

Answer (score 4):

Let $M$ be the Turing machine recognizing $B$.

## Hint

For a Turing machine, try to encode the running time required for $M$ to accept it into itself, so that one can simulate $M$ on it without going into infinite loop.

## Complete Answer

> Let $f$ be a computable bijection from $\mathbb{N}_0^2$ to $\mathbb{N}_0$, where $\mathbb{N}_0$ is the set of non-negative integers.
>
>  
>  Define a state of a Turing machine to be *isolated* if no state can be transitioned to it and it cannot be transitioned to any state. Obviously adding or deleting isolated states does not affect the function of a Turing machine.
>
>  
>  Define $M_d$ to be a decidable Turing machine, which works as follows on input <$M_w$> where $M_w$ is a Turing machine.
>
> 1. Compute the number $n$ of isolated states in $M_w$.
> 2. Let $(n_1,n_2)=f^{-1}(n)$.
> 3. Let $M_w'$ be the Turing machine that is almost the same as $M_w$ except it has $n_1$ isolated states.
> 4. Simulate $M$ on <$M_w'$> with at most $n_2$ steps.
> 5. If $M$ accepts, accept; otherwise, reject.
>
> Consider $M_i$ (recall $M$ accepts <$M_i$>). Suppose $M$ runs in total $n_2$ steps on <$M_i$> and $M_i$ has $n_1$ isolated states. Let $M_i'$ be the Turing machine that is almost the same as $M_i$ except it has $f(n_1, n_2)$ isolated states. Now $M_i'$ and $M_i$ are functionally equivalent, and easy to see <$M_i'$> is accepted by $M_d$.
>
>  
>  On the other hand, suppose <$M_w$> is accepted by $M_d$ and $M_w$ has $n=f(n_1,n_2)$ isolated states. Let $M_w'$ be the Turing machine that is almost the same as $M_w$ except it has $n_1$ isolated states. Now $M_w'$ and $M_w$ are functionally equivalent, and easy to see <$M_w'$> is accepted by $M$.
>
>  
>  So the language deciding by $M_d$ is what we want.

Comment: Thank u so much for your answer...... could you please see this question also https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/89151/show-that-the-collection-of-turing-recognizable-languages-is-closed-under-homomo?noredirect=1#comment191694_89151

Comment: It is not clear for me why you put your solution in this form ...... what is the intuition behind your solution, could you clarify this please?

Comment: @Idonotknow The hint part is the intuition.

Comment: Could you please look at this question if you have time? ...... Many thanks!

Comment: Sorry here it is https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/89479/a-second-question-on-show-a-tm-recognizable-language-of-tms-can-be-expressed-by/89486#89486

Comment: Why you took the the domain & codomain of $f$ as though?

Comment: @Idonotknow $f$ is used to make the number of isolated states of a TM be able to represent two numbers (the number of isolated states of the original TM and the required steps for $M$ to run on the original TM).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much simpler answer that uses the same idea as @xskxzr's answer. I found the bijection used in that answer not really necessary: it's much simpler to just directly store the number of steps itself in the description.

## Hint

For each description accepted by the original recognizer, construct a modified equivalent description that also stores the number of steps required by the recognizer to accept. A decider can then read this number and then simulate the original recognizer for this many steps.

## Solution

As in the answer by @xskxzr, define an *isolated state* to be a state with no transitions to and from it. Hence, for any description, we are free to choose the number of isolated states to be any arbitrary integer, without changing the functionality of the description. Hence, this becomes a mechanism to store an arbitrary non-negative integer in a description.

Now suppose we have a machine that recognizes $\{X_1, X_2, X_3, \ldots\}$, where each description $X_i$ is accepted by the recognizer in $n_i$ steps.

Now define descriptions $Y_i$ which are functionally equivalent to $X_i$ except with $n_i$ isolated states. We can now easily construct a decider that decides $\{Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, \ldots\}$ by first counting the number $n$ of isolated states in the input string $Y$, and then simulating the original recognizer with $n$ steps. Clearly, there's a one-to-one correspondence between $X_i$ and $Y_i$, and the decider will always terminate.