# A second question on "Show a TM-recognizable language of TMs can be expressed by TM-description language of equivalent TMs"

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, computability, undecidability

Let B={M1,M2,...} be a Turing-recognizable language consisting of TM descriptions. Show that there is a decidable language C consisting of TM descriptions s.t. every machine in B has an equivalent machine in C and vice versa.

I saw a hint on solving this question which is given in the following picture:
[image]

But I have a difficulty in constructing such enumerator $E_{0}$, Also how will I show that every machine described in $B$ has an equivalent machine in $C$ and vice versa, could anyone help me in doing so?

Also it is worth to say that the solution of this problem is found here:

[Show a TM-recognizable language of TMs can be expressed by TM-description language of equivalent TMs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14680/show-a-tm-recognizable-language-of-tms-can-be-expressed-by-tm-description-langua)

But I could not understand it. could anyone explain the solution for me in a simple way ? and in a way depending on the above hints?

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: "But I could not understand it. could anyone explain the solution for me in a simple way ? and in a way depending on the above hints? " -- you need to be more specific. What exactly didn't you understand?

Comment: @Raphael  all the solution I did not understand ..... this is why I asked the question another time.

Comment: @Raphael  how can I change images into words on this site ..... could you please tell me?

Comment: 1) People won't be able to give you another answer unless you say what you didn't understand. 2) You type the words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the padding lemma: given $\langle M \rangle$ we can compute $\langle N \rangle$ where $N$ is equivalent to $M$, but has a longer representation. (Essentially, we can always add more irrelevant states to a TM, effectively.)

Then, define $E_0$ to do the following:

- Run $E$ until $M_1$ is produced.
- Let $N_1 = M_1$
- Output $N_1$
- Continue running $E$ until $M_2$ is produced.
- Let $N_2$ be $M_2$, after as many paddings as needed to make its representation larger than $N_1$.
- Output $N_2$
- Continue running $E$ until $M_3$ is produced.
- Let $N_3$ be $M_3$, after as many paddings as needed to make its representation larger than $N_2$.
- Output $N_3$
- And so on.

By construction, $E_0$ prints larger and larger strings, hence its enumerated language is decidable: this is the wanted language C.

We now need to check the quivalence. For any $N_i$ in the language enumerated by $E_0$, we find an equivalent $M_i$ enumerated by $E$. Vice versa, for any $M_i$ in the language enumerated by $E$, we find an equivalent $N_i$ enumerated by $E_0$.

Comment: Do you mean the pumping lemma?

Comment: @Idonotknow No, I mean the padding lemma, as in https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/khomskii/recursion/notes3.pdf

Comment: Is this a proof of the equivalence only ?

Comment: @Idonotknow No, this proves the full question:  "Show that there is a decidable language C consisting of TM descriptions s.t. every machine in B has an equivalent machine in C and vice versa."